# Why cannot this be saved in Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

NOTE: Setters, getters, constructors are omitted.

I am trying to save a kind of simple object to a Firebase database. Looks something like this(this class exists only to enable me to save a list of TimeForDate):

```
public class ExpectedWorkSchedule {
    private List<TimeForDate> reportByDay; 
}
```

TimeForDate has something like this. This is just a date bundled with an amount of time:

```
public class TimeForDate {

    private MyDate myDate;
    private ConcreteTimeToReport concreteTimeToReport;

}
```

MyDate is a simplification of Date:

```
public class MyDate {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
}
```

The TimeToReport is just minutes and hours bundled:

```
public class ConcreteTimeToReport {

    private int minutes;
    private int hours;
}
```

Here is some code testing it out:

```
        List<TimeForDate> myList = Lists.newArrayList();
        myList.add(new TimeForDate(new MyDate(2014,1,1),new ConcreteTimeToReport(1,1)));
        mFirebaseDatabase.getReference(mLoginHolder.getUser().getUid()).child("Test").setValue(new ExpectedWorkSchedule(myList));
```

End up with a stacktrace ending like this:

`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: . Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'`

The way I see it I am storing integers here and I don't understand where firebase is getting its dot from, the symbol it seems to be complaining about. I don't get it, what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know Firebase but is there any chance that someone calls `toString()` on one of the elements, e.g. `ExpectedWorkSchedule`? Or might the db try to use the property path, e.g. it creates something like `myDate.year` etc. as the key?

Comment: The first thing I already thought about and sadly that is not it. I already removed my toStrings. The property path would surprise my but I don't have a better guess at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was simple but not satisfying at all. Instead of using the class ExpectedWorkSchedule, I'm saving the list immediately like this:

```
    List<TimeForDate> myList = Lists.newArrayList();
    myList.add(new TimeForDate(new MyDate(2014,1,1),new ConcreteTimeToReport(1,1)));
    mFirebaseDatabase.getReference(mLoginHolder.getUser().getUid()).child("Test").setValue(myList);
```

I cannot understand why the wrapping class would cause a use of '.' but apparently it does.